# Java ASM - Current frame's stack size doesn't match stackmap

Tags: java, kotlin, java-bytecode-asm

I'm writing a stack-based esolang that compiles to JVM bytecode, but when I run a basic program, it errors with `Current frame's stack size doesn't match stackmap.`
Full error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Instruction type does not match stack map
Exception Details:
  Location:
    Hello.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V @33: return
  Reason:
    Current frame's stack size doesn't match stackmap.
  Current Frame:
    bci: @33
    flags: { }
    locals: { '[Ljava/lang/String;', 'java/util/Scanner' }
    stack: { }
  Stackmap Frame:
    bci: @33
    flags: { }
    locals: { '[Ljava/lang/String;', 'java/util/Scanner' }
    stack: { integer }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: bb00 0959 b200 0fb7 0013 4c2b b600 1703
    0x0000010: b600 1d12 1e64 5999 000a b200 225f b600
    0x0000020: 28b1
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@33,{Object[#42],Object[#9]},{Integer})

        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Github (code is too large to put here): https://github.com/LengthLang/LengthJVM/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/nailuj29gaming/lengthjvm/Compile.kt
Classfile: https://github.com/LengthLang/LengthJVM/blob/master/Hello.class

Comment: The current frame has no `integer` in the stack.

Comment: how can i ensure the stack is empty before returning?

Comment: When you're generating bytecode, you just have to get this right. When two branches converge on a single label, they have to have the same stack frame. At one level it's a pain to deal with this problem, at another level it's far better than if there was no checking and you just got a runtime exception.

Comment: Normal programming languages don’t have this problem, as they work with statements and expressions and control flow directives are also statements or expressions. Your language on the other hand, seems to support arbitrary push and pop operations, so it’s possible to formulate a program that is syntactically valid but doesn’t obey the restrictions of Java bytecode. You’ll have to implement a check and produce a compiler error in this case.

Comment: The language is underspecified. What does a `pop` with an empty stack do?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Crashes the program. Link to esolangs.org article: https://esolangs.org/wiki/Length

Comment: @Holger is there a way i can print the stack in between instructions?

Comment: Use a `CheckClassAdapter`. It does all the validation too, but complains if you didn't use it right.

Comment: And crashes the program? When? At compile time? Or at runtime? The JVM doesn't allow you to write bytecode that would do that.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn the reference implementation (an interpreter) just crashes on a stack underflow

Comment: You can not use Java bytecode in that way; it simply forbids code that would crash. Or you consider the `VerifyError` as a kind of crash, but it happens even before any instruction has been executed. You can use the classes in the [`analysis` package to predict the contents of the stack](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/tree/analysis/package-summary.html), if not statically predictable, you don’t need to try to run the bytecode anyway…